# can not start teradata database using "tpa start"

Tags: teradata

when i try to logon bteq, i get the following error,

```
*** Warning: RDBMS CRASHED OR SESSIONS RESET.  RECOVERY IN PROGRESS.
```

and then i try to restart the database,

```
pdestate -a
```

status:

```
PDE state: DOWN/HARDSTOP
```

start:

```
/etc/init.d/tpa start
```

result:

```
Teradata Database Initiator service is starting...
Teradata Database Initiator service started successfully.
```

then check the status again:

```
PDE state: DOWN/HARDSTOP
```

i tried many times, but still can not start database, don't know the reason,

Comment: Assuming this is a TD Express VM (otherwise you should contact TD support immediately): Check `/var/log/messages` for errors after the most recent `#TPA START` event.

Comment: Jun  5 01:39:33 UNITY recond[8829]: DEGRADED: TdatTools: 29003 #PdeMain NOT started; unexpected reboot detected. Please refer /var/opt/teradata/tdtemp/Pani
cLoopDetected file to resolve this issue.

Comment: Seems there were several reboots in a short time frame while Teradata was starting up. Remove that file `/var/opt/teradata/tdtemp/PanicLoopDetected` and try again

Comment: #BOOT DETECT: seconds(190) is less than g->t1_boot_time_interval: 300

Comment: Teradata waits *n* seconds after Linux boot before starting. 300-190 = 110 seconds later it should have been started :-)

Comment: yes, it works now, thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the "Messages" manual:

Remove file
`13821 Crash loop detected during TPA initialization.  Explanation: In order to prevent PDE initialization from looping forever when an error prevents it from completing, it is only automatically restarted three times. After three unsuccessful initialization attempts, this message is issued and restart attempts are discontinued, leaving PDE down.`

```
rm /var/opt/teradata/tdtemp/PanicLoopDetected
```

To start Teradata DBMS use

```
/etc/init.d/tpa start
```

To confirm that the database has come up, type

```
pdestate -a
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

After giving the command, wait a minute or so and give the same command again. Keep trying. After a few trails (minutes), the database will be started. Looks weird, but works :- )